# How to load tableview based on button values with custom cells?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uibutton, custom-cell

In my app I want to display a tableview(custom cells) based on button tags,when I am clicking on my 1st button it is showing empty table view and clicking on 2nd button it is showing 1st button data.
Here is my Code upto now i tried,
I am Calling my IBAction button in ViewDidLoad Method,

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
 value1=0;
 [self details:nil];
}
```

Here is my IBAction Method,

```
-(IBAction)details:(id)sender
{
  value1 = 0;
  detaiLine.hidden = NO;
  rewardLine.hidden = YES;
  [testTableView reloadData];
}
```

Here is my tableViewDataSource Methods,

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
 {
   return 1;
 }
 -(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
 return responseArray.count;
}
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
if (value1 == 0)
{
    return 104;
}
if(value1 == 1)
{
    return 180;
}
return 0;
}
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  if (value1 == 0)
        {
            static NSString *cellId = @"Cell1";
            ContestDetailCell1 * cell = (ContestDetailCell1 *)[contestTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellId];
            if (cell == nil)
            {
                NSArray *myNib;
                myNib = [[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"ContestDetailCell1" owner:self options:nil];
                cell = [myNib lastObject];
            }
      }
if(value1 == 1)
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell2";
    ContestDetailCell2 *cell = (ContestDetailCell2 *)[contestTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *myNib;
        myNib = [[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"ContestDetailCell2" owner:self options:nil];
        cell =[myNib objectAtIndex:0];
    }
}
```

What is the problem in my code.

Comment: In viewDidLoad: you have posted **value=0;**, is it a typo or like in code, because then value1 is not set at all, when your table loads for the 1st time. Also, I guess heightForRowAtIndexPath doesn't get called in reloadData. Please check.

Comment: @user3300864 i will check n inform u

Comment: @user3300864 heightForRowAtIndexPath is calling.

Comment: Your nib is not initialised may be. are you registering your xib ?

Answer (score 0):

You are not assigning tag value to your value1 variable. Try this code,

```
-(IBAction)details:(id)sender
{
  value1 = sender.tag;
  detaiLine.hidden = NO; 
  rewardLine.hidden = YES;
  [testTableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: i am not using tags.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have not implemented your logic correctly. I didn't understand why you are calling IBAction from viewdidload. 
Please find this as a work around,

1. add tag for each button in xib or using code.
2. In your IBAction Method get the tag and identify the button as follows,

   -(IBAction)details:(id)sender
   {
     value1 = sender.tag;
     \\your remaining code here
   }
3. Using this value1 load your data in table view.

Hope this will help you. Please correct me if i'm wrong. :P